# rspec for Delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, delayed-job, rspec2

I am trying to write a rspec for delayed job.

Currently I use delayed job as follows:

```
class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController
...
MailingJob.new(@incoming_mail.id).perform
...
end
```

Then in /lib/mailing_job.rb:

```
class MailingJob < Struct.new(:mailing_id)
  def perform
  .......
```

How can I test that with rspec? Right now I have:

**/spec/lib/mailing_job/mailingjob_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MailingJob do

  include DelayedJobSpecHelper

  it "should have been worked on if I do something that queues jobs" do
    @incoming_mail = IncomingMail.create(.........)
    MailingJob.new(@incoming_mail.id).perform
    #IncomingMail.method_that_queues_jobs
    work_off
    MailingJob.should be_worked_on
  end
end
```

**/spec/lib/delayed_job_spec_helper.rb**

```
module DelayedJobSpecHelper
  # http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=230
  def work_off
    Delayed::Job.all.each do |job|
      job.payload_object.perform
      job.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

But this errors with:

```
 1) MailingJob should have been worked on if I do something that queues jobs
     Failure/Error: MailingJob.should be_worked_on
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `worked_on?' for MailingJob:Class
     # ./spec/lib/mailing_job/mailingjob_spec.rb:19
```

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're queueing your job incorrectly in the controller. `perform` is called by the worker, not by you.

`Delayed::Job.enqueue MailingJob.new(@incoming_mail.id)`

Similarly, don't call `perform` in your spec, that's what `work_off` does.

The structure of the spec should be this:

- Access controller method that queues the job
- Tell DelayedJob to work off the queue
- Check to see that it did what it was supposed to do

I'm not sure where `be_worked_on` comes in, as `worked_on?` is not defined anywhere in DelayedJob (and indeed, is the cause of your error). I would instead check something was done, like a mail was sent, or whatever your job is supposed to do.